# Android Get foreign App on English Phone

Tags: android, google-play

Hi I need to get an app thats registered to the Irish Google Play Store but I'm in England. Does anyone know how I can do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SnapPea](http://www.snappea.com/).

It's a software for controlling you device through your PC or through web. It also has a kind of play store on the windows version where you can find and install any app regardless of where you are.

Answer (score 1):

Try a couple of these methods:

1. Use a VPN and connect to an Ireland server to get a Irish IP. I use VyprVPN (www.goldenfrog.com/vyprvpn) and they have a3 day free trial.
2. Download the AppBrain App Market app from Google Play. You can use this app to get around country restrictions.